# Ignoring blank email address input field Google Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have an HTML form which contains email addresses from various suppliers. I am creating a kind of mail merge function so I can send all the contacts a personalised email when the form is submitted. Here is my .gs file:

```
function sendEmail(form) {
  const sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(sSheet.getId());
  const documentUrl = file.getUrl();

  /* var toEmail = form.toAddress;  
  var ccEmail = form.ccAddress;  
  var fromEmail = "****@*****.com";
  var subject = form.subject;
  var message = form.message;   */


  var toEmail = "";  
  var fromEmail = "****@*****.com";
  var message = "";

var hotelAddresses = [
            form.toAddress1,
            form.toAddress2,
            form.toAddress3,
            form.toAddress4,
            form.toAddress5,
            form.toAddress6,
            form.toAddress7,
            form.toAddress8,
            form.toAddress9,
            form.toAddress10,
            form.toAddress11,
            form.toAddress12,
            form.toAddress13,
            form.toAddress14,
            form.toAddress15,
            form.toAddress16,
            form.toAddress17,
            form.toAddress18,
            form.toAddress19,
            form.toAddress20,
            form.toAddress21,
            form.toAddress22,
            form.toAddress23,
            form.toAddress24,
            form.toAddress25,
            form.toAddress26,
            form.toAddress27,
            form.toAddress28,
            form.toAddress29,
            form.toAddress30,
            form.toAddress31,
            form.toAddress32,
            form.toAddress33,
];

var contactNames = [
            form.contactName1,
            form.contactName2,
            form.contactName3,
            form.contactName4,
            form.contactName5,
            form.contactName6,
            form.contactName7,
            form.contactName8,
            form.contactName9,
            form.contactName10,
            form.contactName11,
            form.contactName12,
            form.contactName13,
            form.contactName14,
            form.contactName15,
            form.contactName16,
            form.contactName17,
            form.contactName18,
            form.contactName19,
            form.contactName20,
            form.contactName21,
            form.contactName22,
            form.contactName23,
            form.contactName24,
            form.contactName25,
            form.contactName26,
            form.contactName27,
            form.contactName28,
            form.contactName29,
            form.contactName30,
            form.contactName31,
            form.contactName32,
            form.contactName33,            
];

var days = [
            form.day1,
            form.day2,
            form.day3,
            form.day4,
            form.day5,
            form.day6,
            form.day7,
            form.day8,
            form.day9,
            form.day10,
            form.day11,
            form.day12,
            form.day13,
            form.day14,
            form.day15,
            form.day16,
            form.day17,
            form.day18,
            form.day19,
            form.day20,
            form.day21,
            form.day22,
            form.day23,
            form.day24,
            form.day25,
            form.day26,
            form.day27,
            form.day28,
            form.day29,
            form.day30,
            form.day31,
            form.day32,
            form.day33,            
];

var dates = [
            form.date1,
            form.date2,
            form.date3,
            form.date4,
            form.date5,
            form.date6,
            form.date7,
            form.date8,
            form.date9,
            form.date10,
            form.date11,
            form.date12,
            form.date13,
            form.date14,
            form.date15,
            form.date16,
            form.date17,
            form.date18,
            form.date19,
            form.date20,
            form.date21,
            form.date22,
            form.date23,
            form.date24,
            form.date25,
            form.date26,
            form.date27,
            form.date28,
            form.date29,
            form.date30,
            form.date31,
            form.date32,
            form.date33,            
];

var times = [
            form.time1,
            form.time2,
            form.time3,
            form.time4,
            form.time5,
            form.time6,
            form.time7,
            form.time8,
            form.time9,
            form.time10,
            form.time11,
            form.time12,
            form.time13,
            form.time14,
            form.time15,
            form.time16,
            form.time17,
            form.time18,
            form.time19,
            form.time20,
            form.time21,
            form.time22,
            form.time23,
            form.time24,
            form.time25,
            form.time26,
            form.time27,
            form.time28,
            form.time29,
            form.time30,
            form.time31,
            form.time32,
            form.time33,            
];

var additionalInfo = [
            form.additional1,
            form.additional2,
            form.additional3,
            form.additional4,
            form.additional5,
            form.additional6,
            form.additional7,
            form.additional8,
            form.additional9,
            form.additional10,
            form.additional11,
            form.additional12,
            form.additional3,
            form.additional14,
            form.additional15,
            form.additional16,
            form.additional17,
            form.additional18,
            form.additional19,
            form.additional20,
            form.additional21,
            form.additional22,
            form.additional23,
            form.additional24,
            form.additional25,
            form.additional26,
            form.additional27,
            form.additional28,
            form.additional29,
            form.additional30,
            form.additional31,
            form.additional32,
            form.additional33,            
];

for(var i = 0; i<times.length; i++){



var subject = "Meeting - " + days[i] + ", " + dates[i] + " at " + times[i];
toEmail = hotelAddresses[i];
message = "Dear " + contactNames[i] + "," 

          +"<br><br>"+

          "Please confirm the meeting on " + days[i] + " " + dates[i] + " at " + times[i] + "." + "<br>" + "<br>" +

          additionalInfo[i] +

          " If you could kindly let me know if you are able to confirm that would be great." + "<br>" + "<br>" +

          "Many thanks and I look forward to hearing from you soon." + "<br>" + "<br>" +

          "Yours sincerely," + "<br>" + "<br>" +

          form.yourName + "<br>" + "<br>"

          + "<em><b>" + form.yourPosition + "</b></em> <br><br>" +

          "<span style='color:#0e216d'><b>  Company name. </b>"  + "<br>" +






  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    toEmail,         // recipient
    subject,                 // subject 
    'test', {                        // body
      htmlBody: message                 // advanced options
    }
  ); 
}
}
```

It works fine except that sometimes the input fields for email will be blank, in which case I need the script to ignore that supplier and continue to run. At the moment it is obviously hitting the empty input and stopping the execution.

I presume I need a conditional statement of sorts... something along the lines of if(hotelAddresses[i] != null) {}

But I cannot work out where to insert this...

Additional: 31 Aug 18

For the HTML I have a series of objects (33 in total) that are all set up like this:

```
   <input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="check" checked>

   <input type="text" id="name1" class="contactNameInput" name="toAddress1">

   <input type="text" id="contactName1" class="contactNameInput mailName" name="contactName1">

   <input type="text" id="time1" class="contactNameInput hidden mailTime" name="time1">

   <input type="text" id="day1" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDay" name="day1">

   <input type="text" id="date1" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDate" name="date1">

   <textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional1" name="additional1" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>

   <div class="preview1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to separate the cases with and without `hotelAddresses[i]` using a script like `if(hotelAddresses[i] != null) {}`. When my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Do you want to add after `"<span style='color:#0e216d'><b>  Company name. </b>"  + "<br>" +`? In the current script, it's `"<span style='color:#0e216d'><b>  Company name. </b>"  + "<br>" + GmailApp.sendEmail(...)`. If you want to add more strings, please put them. If you don't want to add, please remove the last `+`.
- I think that the script of `if(hotelAddresses[i] != null) {}` can be used in the for loop.

The script which reflected above is as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modified script, the script of for loop was modified.

```
for(var i = 0; i<times.length; i++) {
  var toEmail = hotelAddresses[i];
  if (toEmail) {
    var subject = "subject";
    var message = "messages";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(toEmail, subject, 'test', {htmlBody: message});
  } else {

    // do something

  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, `subject` and `message` are replaced by `"subject"` and `"messages"`, respectively. So please modify them for your situation.
- If you want to do something when `hotelAddresses[i]` is null, please modify `// do something`.

  - If you don't want to do something when `hotelAddresses[i]` is null, please remove `else {}`.

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for this. So simple!! Thanks for your help

Comment: Just another question actually if you don't mind - I added a sample of the HTML to the bottom of my question. So the form contains a series of 33 of these objects. Now, I need to add one more condition into my email sender so that the email only sends when the checkbox is ticked. I already have some JS to change the CSS and make these objects disabled if the checkbox is unticked, but how can I then stop the email being sent if this is the case?

Comment: @DaveB1 I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice about your new question. At first, for your 1st question, did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it?

Comment: @DaveB1 About your new question, I couldn't understand whole script from your snippet because of my poor skill. I'm really sorry for this. So I cannot comment a concrete modification point. But I can propose a scenario. If you don't want to send an email when a checkbox is not checked, you can achieve it by retrieving the value of the checkbox from HTML to GAS using google.script.run. In this case, for example, if you use a submit button, please send the value to GAS when the submit button is clicked. At GAS side, please process the mail using the value.

Comment: @DaveB1 I'm sorry I couldn't comment the concrete solution. This reason is due to my skill. I apologize for this situation to you. If you want the concrete answer, can you post it as a new question? If you post it, please add the detail information. It will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot - please see link here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112453/google-apps-script-do-not-send-email-for-checkbox-is-unchecked

Comment: @DaveB1 Thank you for replying and posting it. But I confirmed that an answer has already been posted. I think that the answer leads to the solution.