# Google Apps Script - do not send email for checkbox is unchecked

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following HTML file written in the script editor within google sheets:

```
<body>

      <form>

      <div class="even group">

          <input type="text" id="yourName" class="contactNameInput" name="yourName" placeholder="Your name">

          <input type="text" id="yourPosition" class="contactNameInput" name="yourPosition" placeholder="Your position">

      </div>



      <div class="odd group">

           <input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="check" checked>

           <input type="text" id="name1" class="contactNameInput" name="toAddress1">

           <input type="text" id="contactName1" class="contactNameInput mailName" name="contactName1">

           <input type="text" id="time1" class="contactNameInput hidden mailTime" name="time1">

           <input type="text" id="day1" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDay" name="day1">

           <input type="text" id="date1" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDate" name="date1">

           <textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional1" name="additional1" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>

           <div class="preview1"></div>       

      </div>



      <div class="even group">

           <input type="checkbox" id="check2" class="check" checked>

           <input type="text" name="toAddress2" id="name2" class="contactNameInput">

           <input type="text" id="contactName2" class="contactNameInput mailName" name="contactName2">

           <input type="text" id="time2" class="contactNameInput hidden mailTime" name="time2">

           <input type="text" id="day2" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDay" name="day2">

           <input type="text" id="date2" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDate" name="date2">

           <textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional2" name="additional2" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>

           <div class="preview1"></div>       

           </div>



// ... there are 33 of these objects in total - all identical except for the ascending Ids...

      <div class="odd group">

           <input type="checkbox" id="check33" class="check" checked>

           <input type="text" name="toAddress33" id="name33" class="contactNameInput">

           <input type="text" id="contactName33" class="contactNameInput mailName" name="contactName33">

           <input type="text" id="time33" class="contactNameInput hidden mailTime" name="time33">

           <input type="text" id="day33" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDay" name="day33">

           <input type="text" id="date33" class="contactNameInput hidden mailDate" name="date33">

           <textarea class="additional contactNameInput" id="additional33" name="additional33" placeholder="Additional requests..."></textarea>

           <div class="preview1"></div> 

       </div>



                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary googleGreen" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Sending">Invite hotels</button>

      </form>

     <script>





             $(".additional").focus(function(){
             $('.dearName').html(function() { 
                return $(this)                
                  .closest('.preview1')          
                  .siblings('.mailName')         
                  .val();
              });
              $('.meetingDay').html(function() { 
                return $(this)                
                  .closest('.preview1')          
                  .siblings('.mailDay')         
                  .val();
              });
              $('.meetingTime').html(function() { 
                return $(this)                
                  .closest('.preview1')          
                  .siblings('.mailTime')         
                  .val();
              });
              $('.meetingDate').html(function() { 
                return $(this)                
                  .closest('.preview1')          
                  .siblings('.mailDate')         
                  .val();
              });
              $(this).siblings('div:first').slideDown();
              }).blur(function() {
              $(this).siblings('div:first').slideUp();
              });       


             $(".additional").keyup(function() {
                $(this).next('div').find('.addedText').html($(this).val());
                });

             $(".preview1").html("<p> Dear <span class='dearName'></span></p> <br> <p>Please can we meet on <span class='meetingDay'></span> <span class='meetingDate'></span> at <span class='meetingTime'></span>.</p><br><p><span class='addedText'></span>If you could kindly let me know if you are able to confirm that would be great.</p><br><p>Many thanks and I look forward to hearing from you soon.</p><br><p>Yours sincerely,</p>");

             // $(".dearName").html($(".dearName").prev('.preview1').siblings().find('.mailName')val());




     var idArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33];

    var hotelName = "";
    var hotelAddress = "";
    var hotelContact = "";
    var hotelTel = "";
    var hotelEmail = "";

function onSuccess(test){
// var hotelArray = test;
for(var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++){
hotelName = test[i].name;
hotelAddress = test[i].address;
hotelContact = test[i].contact;
hotelTel = test[i].tel;
hotelEmail = test[i].email;
time = test[i].time;
day = test[i].day;
date = test[i].date;


$("#name" + idArray[i]).val(hotelEmail);
$("#contactName" + idArray[i]).val(hotelContact);
$("#time" + idArray[i]).val(time);
$("#day" + idArray[i]).val(day);
$("#date" + idArray[i]).val(date);

}

} google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).findHotel();

        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]
                .addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    google.script.run
                        .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
                            google.script.host.close()
                        })
                        .withFailureHandler(function(result) {
                            console.log("f %s", result)
                        })
                        //.withFailureHandler(function(result){toastr.error('Process failed', result)})
                        .sendEmail(e.currentTarget);
                        })};


          $('.btn').on('click', function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.button('loading');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $this.button('reset');
            }, 15000);           
        }); 

$(".check").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("checkDisabled");
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass("disabledInput");
    if($(this).siblings().hasClass("disabledInput")) {
      $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", false);
    }})




 $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", true);

             $('.dearName').html(function() { 
                return $(this)                
                  .closest('.preview1')          
                  .siblings('.mailName')         
                  .val();
              });

    </script>

</body>
```

Each of the class 'group' divs within the form represents one client and I have a .gs file which then sends an email on submit to all clients so long as there is an email address in the relevant field:

```
function sendEmail(form) {
  const sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(sSheet.getId());
  const documentUrl = file.getUrl();

  /* var toEmail = form.toAddress;  
  var ccEmail = form.ccAddress;  
  var fromEmail = "****@****.com";
  var subject = form.subject;
  var message = form.message;   */


  var toEmail = "";  
  var fromEmail = "****@****.com";
  var message = "";

var hotelAddresses = [
            form.toAddress1,
            form.toAddress2,
            form.toAddress3,
            form.toAddress4,
            form.toAddress5,
            form.toAddress6,
            form.toAddress7,
            form.toAddress8,
            form.toAddress9,
            form.toAddress10,
            form.toAddress11,
            form.toAddress12,
            form.toAddress13,
            form.toAddress14,
            form.toAddress15,
            form.toAddress16,
            form.toAddress17,
            form.toAddress18,
            form.toAddress19,
            form.toAddress20,
            form.toAddress21,
            form.toAddress22,
            form.toAddress23,
            form.toAddress24,
            form.toAddress25,
            form.toAddress26,
            form.toAddress27,
            form.toAddress28,
            form.toAddress29,
            form.toAddress30,
            form.toAddress31,
            form.toAddress32,
            form.toAddress33,
];

var contactNames = [
            form.contactName1,
            form.contactName2,
            form.contactName3,
            form.contactName4,
            form.contactName5,
            form.contactName6,
            form.contactName7,
            form.contactName8,
            form.contactName9,
            form.contactName10,
            form.contactName11,
            form.contactName12,
            form.contactName13,
            form.contactName14,
            form.contactName15,
            form.contactName16,
            form.contactName17,
            form.contactName18,
            form.contactName19,
            form.contactName20,
            form.contactName21,
            form.contactName22,
            form.contactName23,
            form.contactName24,
            form.contactName25,
            form.contactName26,
            form.contactName27,
            form.contactName28,
            form.contactName29,
            form.contactName30,
            form.contactName31,
            form.contactName32,
            form.contactName33,            
];

var days = [
            form.day1,
            form.day2,
            form.day3,
            form.day4,
            form.day5,
            form.day6,
            form.day7,
            form.day8,
            form.day9,
            form.day10,
            form.day11,
            form.day12,
            form.day13,
            form.day14,
            form.day15,
            form.day16,
            form.day17,
            form.day18,
            form.day19,
            form.day20,
            form.day21,
            form.day22,
            form.day23,
            form.day24,
            form.day25,
            form.day26,
            form.day27,
            form.day28,
            form.day29,
            form.day30,
            form.day31,
            form.day32,
            form.day33,            
];

var dates = [
            form.date1,
            form.date2,
            form.date3,
            form.date4,
            form.date5,
            form.date6,
            form.date7,
            form.date8,
            form.date9,
            form.date10,
            form.date11,
            form.date12,
            form.date13,
            form.date14,
            form.date15,
            form.date16,
            form.date17,
            form.date18,
            form.date19,
            form.date20,
            form.date21,
            form.date22,
            form.date23,
            form.date24,
            form.date25,
            form.date26,
            form.date27,
            form.date28,
            form.date29,
            form.date30,
            form.date31,
            form.date32,
            form.date33,            
];

var times = [
            form.time1,
            form.time2,
            form.time3,
            form.time4,
            form.time5,
            form.time6,
            form.time7,
            form.time8,
            form.time9,
            form.time10,
            form.time11,
            form.time12,
            form.time13,
            form.time14,
            form.time15,
            form.time16,
            form.time17,
            form.time18,
            form.time19,
            form.time20,
            form.time21,
            form.time22,
            form.time23,
            form.time24,
            form.time25,
            form.time26,
            form.time27,
            form.time28,
            form.time29,
            form.time30,
            form.time31,
            form.time32,
            form.time33,            
];

var additionalInfo = [
            form.additional1,
            form.additional2,
            form.additional3,
            form.additional4,
            form.additional5,
            form.additional6,
            form.additional7,
            form.additional8,
            form.additional9,
            form.additional10,
            form.additional11,
            form.additional12,
            form.additional3,
            form.additional14,
            form.additional15,
            form.additional16,
            form.additional17,
            form.additional18,
            form.additional19,
            form.additional20,
            form.additional21,
            form.additional22,
            form.additional23,
            form.additional24,
            form.additional25,
            form.additional26,
            form.additional27,
            form.additional28,
            form.additional29,
            form.additional30,
            form.additional31,
            form.additional32,
            form.additional33,            
];



for(var i = 0; i<times.length; i++){


var subject = "Meeting - " + days[i] + ", " + dates[i] + " at " + times[i];
toEmail = hotelAddresses[i];
message = "Dear " + contactNames[i] + "," 

          +"<br><br>"+

          "Please can we meet on " + days[i] + " " + dates[i] + " at " + times[i] + "." + "<br>" + "<br>" +

          additionalInfo[i] +

          " If you could kindly let me know if you are able to confirm that would be great." + "<br>" + "<br>" +

          "Many thanks and I look forward to hearing from you soon." + "<br>" + "<br>" +

          "Yours sincerely," + "<br>" + "<br>" +

          form.yourName + "<br>" + "<br>"

          + "<em><b>" + form.yourPosition + "</b></em> <br><br>" +

          "<span style='color:#0e216d'><b>  Company name </b>"  + "<br>" +

          "Company address</span><br>" +

          "<img src='companylogo.jpg' style='width: 50%; margin-top: 10px'>";


if(toEmail) {

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    toEmail,         // recipient
    subject,                 // subject 
    'test', {                        // body
      htmlBody: message                 // advanced options
    }
  ); 
}}
}
```

However, as well as not sending an email when there is no address entered, I need to stop the email from sending when the checkbox is not checked. I'm not quite sure where to start with this...

Comment: You should start by working on a simplified setup. Once your code works for a page with 1 address & checkbox & email, adding more of that same element and extending the behavior should be very simple. To begin, consider logging the data that gets sent to the Apps Script functions. Use Stackdriver (`console.log` from a *.gs* file) if you are at all able, as it provides robust logging, in terms of both interactive objects and log persistence.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of restructuring of your code is probably going to help you a lot here. For example, the `hotelAddresses` array is currently a manually created list of addresses - hard to maintain. I'd begin by using the `group` class on all of the divs to your advantage, as you can select every single one, in order, using the `document.getElementsByClassName("group")` selector. This will return an array of all your group elements.

Now that we have an array of all these groups, we can process them in a much more concise way. For example, creating that hotel addresses array becomes as simple as:

```
var hotelAddresses = [], groupElements = document.getElementsByClassName("group")
for (var i = 1; i < groupElements.length; i++) {
      var isChecked = groupElements[i].getElementsByClassName("check")[0].checked
      var address = groupElements[i].getElementsByClassName("contactNameInput")[0].value

      if (isChecked && address != "") { // Add if is checked and has an address
         hotelAddresses.push(address)
      }
}
```

You can easily add the code for the `contactNames` and other arrays in to this same loop. Maybe even another data structure which is an array of your groups for much easier access.

```
var groups = []
... // Loop code
groups.push({
    address: groupElements[i].getElementsByClassName("contactNameInput")[0].value,
    contactName: ...
})
```

You get the idea! Hope this helps you out a bit.